# SQL - SUM two columns from two tables and write in new Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following situation to solve. I have a Table A with product information and I have a Table B with client purchase history. Now I need to calculate in a new Column "`Sum_product_X`" the Sum of the frequency of the purchases with the value of the product for each `ClientID`. So in this case we know A client has bought `Product A`  5 times, so we need to calculate in the column `sum_producta` the sum of `5 * 5$`

```
  Table A (Product Price Table)
    ----------------------------
    ProductA | ProductB | ProductC

    5$ | 10$ | 15$         



    Table B (Client purchase history)
    -----------------------
    ClientID | Frequency_ProductA |Frequency_ProductB | Sum_ProductA | Sum_ProductB

    Abc123 | 5 | 10 | to be calculated: 5*5 | to be calculated 10*10
```

I need to add that I found out that the SQL support of environment has the following rules:

> Only SELECT statements to data extension or data views in an account
>   or in the parent account Nested Queries UNION JOIN GROUP BY

Table A can be modified. Meaning the structure could be as well the following:

```html
Table A 
-----------------------

Productname | Price
product A | 5
product B | 10
product C | 15
```

Comment: you have fix products  or something more?

Comment: the best way to do this would be to create a view, i dont think you would get the required funcitonality actually storing in a table

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Why so?

Comment: @Sami he would need to do it as a stored procedure to update the stored values wouldnt he?

Comment: Is the products table just one row? Or are there multiple entries in there? Writing the code for your answer may be incorrect without know how the table actually works.

Comment: You should really redesign your tables! Table A to columns Product and Price, Rows A, 5$ and B, 10 $... and Table B to ClientID, Frequency_of_Product, Sum_of_Product.

Comment: The task doesn't seem to make much sense. So you have a history of purchases, but calculate with the current price? Why is there no price in the history table? Usually you buy a product at the price it costs at the time of purchase. Why is this different in your tables?

Answer (score 1):

In traditional relational databases, it's all about normalization.  Or put differently, you should have exactly and only one source of authority.  By creating a new column, you would have multiple sources of "the correct data".  For example, if the frequency increases, and your code forgets to update the column, who is to say which is now the correct value?

Suggest instead, let the RDBMS do the [work for you with a VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createview.html).  Your current schema needs to be normalized better to take advantage of this; I'll tackle that below.

```
CREATE VIEW product_sales AS
  SELECT
   tabA.product_name,
   tabA.product_price,
   tabB.clientID,
   tabC.frequency,
   tabA.product_price * tabC.count AS sum_product_x
  FROM
    tableA AS tabA,
    tableB AS tabB,
    tableC AS tabC
  WHERE
      tabA.product_id = tabC.product_id
  AND tabB.clientID = tabC.client_id;
```

Now, in your queries, you treat the VIEW as just another TABLE for SELECT purposes:

```
SELECT * FROM product_sales ORDER BY 5 DESC, 1 ASC LIMIT 5;
```

Unfortunately, your current design appears to have a column per product.  That's generally a no-no.  Are you going to add a column for every new product?  I sure hope not.  Instead, normalize your data into separate tables, and link with primary and foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  product_id     CHAR(5)     PRIMARY KEY,
  product_name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  product_price  INTEGER     NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE clients (
 client_id      VARCHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,
 client_name    VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE client_purchaces (
 client_id     VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
 product_id    CHAR(5)    NOT NULL,
 count         INTEGER    NOT NULL,

 FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES clients(client_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES products(product_id),
 CONSTRAINT CHECK (count >= 0)
);
```

With this structure, when a new product comes in, you simply add a row (`INSERT INTO products ...`), rather than changing the schema (`ALTER TABLE ...`).  Further, when a client makes a purchase, you simply insert or update a single integer, rather than overwriting rows, or altering your schema.  Further, with a more normalized design like this, you can have your database do your work for you (e.g., `CREATE VIEW ...`)

Comment: Thanks for this very sophisticated solution! Unfortunately my Queries needs to beginn with Select.

Comment: @Christian Your queries **would** begin with SELECT.  For example, `SELECT * FROM product_sales`.  You'll also note that a VIEW is simply a SELECT statement in disguise.  Look at the definition, above.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to /can't redesign you tables, you could give this a try:

```
UPDATE table_b
SET SUM_ProductA = (Frequency_Product_A * (SELECT ProductA FROM table_a)),
    SUM_ProductB = (Frequency_Product_B * (SELECT ProductB FROM table_a)),
    SUM_ProductC = (Frequency_Product_C * (SELECT ProductC FROM table_a))
```

Otherwise i really recommend the answer of @hunteke !!!!!! (I also mentioned this in my comment)

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
UPDATE tableB 
SET sum_productA = (SELECT Price * Frequency_ProductA FROM tableA WHERE Product = 'ProductA'),
SET sum_productB = (SELECT Price * Frequency_ProductB FROM tableA WHERE Product = 'ProductB');
```

to calculate the columns Sum_ProductA and Sum_ProductB.

However it suppose that Product is the key of your table A